# setInterval and setTimeout speed changes

Tags: javascript, function, slider, settimeout, setinterval

My problem is within some JavaScript:

```
            var mijnfunctie = function(){

    //balk 1 2 3

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#balk1").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 400);
        $("#balk2").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 400);
        $("#balk3").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 400);
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#balk1").animate({"margin-left": "-2000px"}, 400);
        $("#balk2").animate({"margin-left": "4000px"}, 400);
        $("#balk3").animate({"margin-left": "-5000px"}, 400);
    }, 2000);

    //balk 4 5 6

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#balk4").animate({"margin-left": "0"}, 400);
        $("#balk5").animate({"margin-left": "0"}, 400);
        $("#balk6").animate({"margin-left": "0"}, 400);
    }, 3000);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#balk4").animate({"margin-left": "2000px"}, 400);
        $("#balk5").animate({"margin-left": "-4000px"}, 400);
        $("#balk6").animate({"margin-left": "5000px"}, 400);
    }, 5000);


    setInterval(mijnfunctie, 6000);
};

mijnfunctie();
```

this is made for a slider and it works fine. For six times, and after the sixth it's starting to mix up. So somewhere the time isn't right, but where?

Comment: The first one is missing its time argument.

Comment: Can u plz state your more working code so that anyone can understand where the flow is going?

Comment: @JanDvorak - If we don't give argument still code works fine ,but that part of function will be executed at once ,not based on timing

Answer (score 3):

`setInterval` will enqueue a *repeated* function. Since you're doing it at the end of the function you're enqueuing, after twelve seconds, it will run twice. After each six more seconds, the count of them will double. Slowly, this will bring the browser to its knees. You'll have 500 timers set up in mere one minute, 500 000 timers the second minute...

Either move `setInterval` outside of the function you want to repeat, or (better) change it to `setTimeout`(which will enqueue just one occurence of the call).

```
function mijnfunctie(){
   ...
   setTimeout(mijnfunctie, 6000);
}
```

---

Secondly, your first call to `setTimeout` is missing its argument. No matter what the default value is, you should always specify it.

---

Third, if any animation delays by a few seconds, then the subsequent animations will run immediately after. To prevent this, you may want to chain the animations instead of relying on correct timing. In that case, to prevent the pyramid effect (extreme indenting), I suggest this form:

```
function phase1(){
  $(...).animate(..., phase2);
}

function phase2(){
  ...

...

function phaseN(){
  $(...).animate(..., phase1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for everything. When i simply changed my setInterval to setTimeout it worked just fine! I've had some good feedback from you all. Thanks again!

Comment: @GerritMulder You may wish to accept this answer then. Note the empty checkmark beside the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on delay in `setTimeout`, this value means only minimal delay for the function. Instead you should chain those functions.

```
var mijnfunctie = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#balk1").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 400);
        $("#balk2").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 400);
        $("#balk3").animate({"margin-left": "0px"}, 400, function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#balk1").animate({"margin-left": "-2000px"}, 400);
                $("#balk2").animate({"margin-left": "4000px"}, 400);
                $("#balk3").animate({"margin-left": "-5000px"}, 400, function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $("#balk4").animate({"margin-left": "0"}, 400);
                        $("#balk5").animate({"margin-left": "0"}, 400);
                        $("#balk6").animate({"margin-left": "0"}, 400, function () {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $("#balk4").animate({"margin-left": "2000px"}, 400);
                                $("#balk5").animate({"margin-left": "-4000px"}, 400);
                                $("#balk6").animate({"margin-left": "5000px"}, 400, function () {
                                    setTimeout(mijnfunctie, 600);
                                });
                            }, 1600);
                        });
                    }, 600);
                });
            }, 1600);
        });
    }, 0);
};
mijnfunctie();
```

---

anyway I would rather suggest something like that :)

```
(function () {
    var objects = new Array(6),
        index = 0,
        steps = [
            [[0,'0px'],[1, '0px'],[2, '0px']],
            1600,
            [[0,'-2000px'],[1,'4000px'],[2,'-5000px']],
            600,
            [[3,'0px'],[4,'0px'],[5,'0px']],
            1600,
            [[3,'2000px', '-400px', '5000px']],
            600
        ],
        i = 6,
        crawler;

    while(i--) { objects[i] = $('#balk'+(i + 1)); };

    crawler = function () {
        var step, k;
        if (index >= steps.length) index = 0;
        step = steps[index];
        ++index;
        if (typeof(step) == 'number') {
            setTimeout(step, crawler);
        } else {
            k = step.length - 1;
            while(k--) {
                objects[k[0]].animate({'margin-left': step[k[1]]}, 400, (k ? null : crawler)});
            }
        }
    };
    crawler();
}());
```

or something more generic and reusable

Comment: it could be wrote much better, I just changed what OP wrote. I also did not notice what you did - setIterval.

Comment: consider my alternative to the pyramid effect. What do you think of it?

Comment: I would rather pack all changes into some array and generate function that will crawl through that array (as all that functions are same)

Comment: The code should be rewritten into generic form for any number of balks, and you won't have the callback pyramid then anyway.

Comment: @lupatus I was actually thinking (before this question) of writing a frameworklet in the form `do(f1).then(f2).then(f3) ... .end()` where f1...fn would take `self` and `next` as their arguments.

Comment: but f1..fn would be almost the same

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit you are using `setInterval(mijnfunctie, 6000);` function inside the same function that's why it is looping itself and calling     `setInterval(mijnfunctie, 6000);` function multiple times..

Therefore calling     `setInterval(mijnfunctie, 6000);` function only once (where first time is called) is adviced.

Enjoy..!